# After installing node in Windows 10, npm command is failing with error cannot find module 'lru_cache'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Installed Node v14.16.1 in Windows 10 machine. Opened command prompt and typed 'node' that printed

```
D:\>node
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Now after that in another command prompt typed 'npm' that errored

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\>npm
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\classes\range.js
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\classes\comparator.js
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\icando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\node_modules\←[4msemver←[24m\classes\range.js:187:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\classes\\range.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\classes\\comparator.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\unsupported.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\icando\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}

D:\>
```

Can someone help on how to resolve this error. I fairly searched for this error to resolve and none seems to help. I tried uninstalling and installing node.js again but no luck. I Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs Windows 10 installer (Node-v14.16.1-x64.msi) is messy, which I believe caused the error. I've uninstalled and downloaded Windows Binary (.zip) and set the expanded directory in the PATH environment variable. With that, I can be able to use npm command.